# CSS Transition Group Issue when installing React Fine Uploader

Tags: fine-uploader

I'm trying to get a fresh react fine uploader going but keep running into issues with `react-addons-css-transition-group`.

The warning I'm getting is:

> npm WARN react-fine-uploader@1.0.1 requires a peer of
>   react-addons-css-transition-group@0.14.x || 15.x.x but none was
>   installed.

I've installed the latest version of React i.e. 15.5.4 and according to this page, the react-addons-css-transition-group has been deprecated.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-addons-css-transition-group

How do I resolve this issue?

P.S. This is my package.json file as it stands right now.
[image]

Comment: Install the required peer dependency. You can always open up a PR in the React Fine Uploader project that updates to wherever replaces the add-on.

Comment: Thank you. It installed fine. I was concerned that it wouldn't which is why I had installed "react-transition-group" which seems to be the package compatible with React 15.x. However, it appears react-fine-uploader has a dependency on "react-addons-css-transition-group" and "react-transition-group" just wouldn't do it.

Comment: The project will need to be updated

Comment: Yup. Here's the link in case you need it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-addons-css-transition-group

Comment: I created the project, so i already know about this dependency